# Having to Change the Drive constantly in Batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have come across some odd behaviour with a batch script recently that I haven't seen before.

Below is what I have had to do to get my script to work. Below is just a piece of the overall script but shows the issue. In short I am having to constantly switch drives in the code. This becomes an issue when using the blat.exe with the attachment on a different drive.

```
Set DataFile=Test%Date:~-7,2%%Date:~-10,2%.csv

:: Echos the correct name
echo %DataFile%

:: Wouldn't expect to need the two lines below
D:
cd %DATAPATH%

:: If file not present exit
IF NOT EXIST %DataFile% (
    echo No File Exists
    Exit
)
```

What I want to be able to do to simplify things (what I would usually do on other environments)

```
Set DataFile=Test%Date:~-7,2%%Date:~-10,2%.csv

:: Echos the correct name
echo %DataFile%

:: If file not present exit
IF NOT EXIST %DataFile% (
    echo No File Exists
    Exit
)
```

Hopefully that makes sense. It seems to be an environment issue or similar, but I cant find anything obvious.

Thank you for any help.

Edit for solution:

As mentioned in a comment below, the underlying issue sent me on a complete wild goose chase and hence the example provided most probably made little to no sense. The problem was a comment inside of the IF statement which I excluded from the examples provided to keep things clean. Turned out the comment was the problem!

The below does not work and complains about a missing ')'

```
IF NOT EXIST %Filepath%\%FileName% (
    echo the file does not exist
    :: call {path to an executable}
)
.. Continue script
```

The script below does work

```
IF NOT EXIST %Filepath%\%FileName% (
    echo the file does not exist
)

:: call {path to an executable}

.. Continue script
```

Thanks for your help with he issue.

Comment: What does "constantly" mean?  Do you run this more than once per day?  Is this the complete batch file?  If so, the call to `Exit` is redundant, since there are no statements after it.  Also, how are you calling this batch file?  Without changing the drive/dir, it will look in the current directory of the parent process.

Comment: `%DataFile%` is just the file name, so unless your batch file is in the same folder as `%DataFile%`, you are going to have to change the working directory. Alternately, you can just do: `SET DataFile="%DataPath%%DataFile%"` to set the full path. Then you shouldn't need the `CD` command.

Comment: The root cause turned out to be an error I didn't even consider when looking at the script (and hence left out of the example for readability). I had a comment (using '::') inside the IF statement. Even though the closing bracket was on a separate line, if appeared to be getting included in the comment and thus making the if statement incorrect (causing the script to crash out). Updated question to show issue.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is you are quoting both `path1` and `file1` when you assign them a value. This will cause a problem when dealing with full paths:

```
move %path1%%file% %path2%
```

Expands to (using your values):

```
move "path1""file1" "path2"
```

Instead do *not* quote paths and file name which will be concatenated later, rather quote them when they are combined:

```
set path1=C:\My Path\
set file1=myfile.txt
set path2="C:\New Path\"

REM Combined path is quoted.
move "%path1%%file%" %path2%
```

The above expands to:

```
move "C:\My Path\myfile.txt" "C:\New Path\"
```

For your full script, try this:

```
REM Do not quote path/files which are to be combined.
set path1=path1
set file1=file1
set path2="path2"

REM Quote path here since it isn't quoted in the declaration.
IF NOT EXIST "%path1%" (
    md "%path1%"
) 

REM Combined path is quoted.
move "%path1%%file%" %path2%

::exe below is on another drive
call [path_to_exe].exe
```

Comment: Hi Jason, Sorry the quotes included in the above was just habit. I only put quotes around strings when there is a space and tend to use underscores instead of spaces. I Will update the post with the exact batch.

Comment: @ricky89 - I added a comment to your original question. It appears the problem has to do with not setting the full path.